# My altcoin bitcoinj fork is failing when trying to compile an Android wallet

Tags: bitcoinj

I've been sent a bitcoinj fork which is meant to work for the android wallet I'm building. Unfortunately it seems to be causing a failure when tests are run during the wallet compile.

I get the following error message when I try to compile the wallet:

```
Running com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.BluetoothTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.052 sec - in com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.BluetoothTest
Running com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.GenericUtilsTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.039 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.GenericUtilsTest

formatMKOBOValue(com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.GenericUtilsTest)  Time elapsed: 0.032 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[200]0000000000.00> but was:<[35]0000000000.00>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.GenericUtilsTest.formatMKOBOValue(GenericUtilsTest.java:75)

formatUKOBOValue(com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.GenericUtilsTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[200]0000000000000> but was:<[35]0000000000000>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.GenericUtilsTest.formatUKOBOValue(GenericUtilsTest.java:97)

formatValue(com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.GenericUtilsTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[200]0000000.00> but was:<[35]0000000.00>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.GenericUtilsTest.formatValue(GenericUtilsTest.java:53)

Running com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.Base43Test
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.Base43Test
Running com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.CryptoTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.254 sec - in com.machadocrypto.kobocoin_android_wallet.util.CryptoTest

Failed tests: 
GenericUtilsTest.formatMKOBOValue:75 expected:<[200]0000000000.00> but was:<[35]0000000000.00>
GenericUtilsTest.formatUKOBOValue:97 expected:<[200]0000000000000> but was:<[35]0000000000000>
GenericUtilsTest.formatValue:53 expected:<[200]0000000.00> but was:<[35]0000000.00>

Tests run: 13, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

The error is coming from the kobocoinj. I've posted the error message on github

https://github.com/machado-rev/kobocoinj/issues/1

Can anyone give ANY tip on how to move forward from this? I'm just looking for the name of a file to edit that will cause ANY of the numbers in the failure message above to change. Once I'm in the right ball park at least I have something to work with. Right now I'm 99% done but dead in the water.

Any tips or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've changed the MAX_MONEY parameter, so you need to change the tests that depend on it.

[This appears to be the offending file.](https://github.com/machado-rev/kobocoin-android-wallet/blob/89fbe4629c8d60f7a89ffaa1dc56c28ec0678d54/wallet/test/com/kobocoin/android_wallet/util/GenericUtilsTest.java#L32)

P.S. Changing MAX_MONEY will not change the maximum number of coins. See: [Why doesn't changing MAX_MONEY change the maximum number of coins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36612/why-doesnt-changing-max-money-change-the-maximum-number-of-coins)